# Custom Conditions in build defintion in TFS2017 update 1

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

In build definition, I am not able to configure the custom conditions for the tasks in tfs2017 update 1.

This started in tfs2017 update 3. Can you give me an advice to replicate this thing in tfs2017 update 1?

We are planning to configure the custom conditions in build definition. Here, attached custom conditions in tfs 2017 update 3. We want to do this in tfs update 1.

[image]

Comment: The solution is to upgrade to a version that supports the feature you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I further checked this problem. Currently, custom conditions are not supported in version TFS2017 update 1. We recommend that you use the version TFS 2017.3  and  TFS 2018.

In addition, you can also try to upgrade TFS2017 update 1 to TFS 2018.

Regarding custom conditions, please check the document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=yaml#enable-a-custom-condition
[image]

Regarding upgrade your deployment, please check the document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2020